# deploying laravel into Nginx getting error "failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Tags: laravel, nginx, deploying

I have a problem with deploying laravel into my Nginx. I deployed my laravel app thru **github.com**

but when I execute `php artisan config:cache` or `php artisan make:auth`

This is the error I get:

> PHP Warning: 
>   require(/var/www/gafsolutions.com/html/laravel/vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/gafsolutions.com/html/laravel/artisan on line 18 PHP Fatal
>   error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/gafsolutions.com/html/laravel/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
>   /var/www/gafsolutions.com/html/laravel/artisan on line 18

Comment: Did you `composer install` on the server?

Comment: yes, and this is the message..                                                                            
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.               Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.5.x-dev requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extensio                                                                                        n dom is missing from your system.

Answer (score -1):

First, make sure you have set up a composer properly `composer install` It will just install all the dependencies as specified in the **composer.lock** file

If you have already installed then run this command:`composer dump-autoload` It will clean up all compiled files and their paths.

After, run this command: `composer update --no-scripts` It will Skips execution of scripts defined in **composer.json** file.

Then run this command: `composer update` It will update your depencencies as they are specified in **composer.json**